# Ember Data 1.0.0: Model name capitalized in URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am transitioning from Ember Data 0.13 to Ember Data 1.0 (beta 1). It seems that the URL constructed for a model is capitalized when it shouldn't. In ED 0.13, capitalization and pluralization occurred automatically and without problems. I suppose the same is still true in ED 1.0, but I must be overlooking something.

```
App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
  // Attributes
  company: DS.attr('string'),

  // Relationships
  users: DS.hasMany('User')
});

App.AccountAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
});
```

In the controller, I create a new record, populate it, and save it.

```
var account = this.store.createRecord('account');
account.set('company', this.get('company'));
account.save();
```

The request URL that Ember Data uses for saving the record is `http://localhost:3000/api/Accounts`. **Why is the plural of the model name capitalized? How do I configure the model/adapter to use `accounts` instead of `Accounts`?**

Comment: this doesn't seems to be occurring in find() in ED 1.0.0. beta 14.1. a type.typekey is producing a lowercase string from the class. in your case 'account'.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a change in the naming convention of model associations is the cause of this issue. Before ED 1.0, an association was declared as shown below.

```
App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
  // Attributes
  company: DS.attr('string'),

  // Relationships
  users: DS.hasMany('App.User')
});
```

In ED 1.0, however, there is no need to use `App.User` to declare an association. Passing the model's name, `user` suffices. Because I capitalized the name of the `Account` model in the `User` model, ED capitalized the name (plural) of the model in the URL.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  // Attributes
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  password_confirmation: DS.attr('string'),

  // Relationships
  account: DS.belongsTo('account') // model name should be lowercase
});
```

Just like you need to pass the lowercase name of the model for creating a new record (`this.store.createRecord('user');`), you also need to use the lowercase model name to specify the model for an association.